# Page swipe using touch

Tags: jquery, jsp, html, jqtouch

I am trying to add page swipe on a JSP page. I have a page which is now scrollable with arrows. For example, if I click or touch the right arrow, a new JSP page gets loaded, similarly the one to the left. But it is annoying to touch only the arrows on mobile devices each time. So I want to make the entire page as swipe. Basically, it should do the same operation as the arrows but by swiping the page. I am using JSP to load the new page with arrows.

Please let me know if you have any ideas. I am trying to use jqtouch but any thoughts from you is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery mobile has some useful handlers for gestures like tap, taphold, swipe, swipeleft, swiperight.  New pages can be loaded on these events.

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/events.html

Comment: great! let me try this and get back asap. I had started trying with the script given here http://padilicious.com/code/touchevents/

Comment: it takes some work acclimate yourself to the jquery mobile framework but once you get the hang of it, you can develop a powerful, clean, organized, cross platform compliant, mobile web app.  me likey

Comment: It works like a charm. As you said, it takes some time but the end result is great. Thank you much!